# req.files return undefined data while req.body is populated

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer, superagent

**Setting:**

- Node.JS(v8.9.4)
- Express(v4.16.2)
- Superagent v3.8.2(https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent) for POST from client
- multer for file upload(v1.3.0)
- React/Babel/Webpack
- CentOS 7,Vultr VPS
- File size limit is expaned to 50mb from `nginx` & `multer`
- Deployed by private git(the version is consistent all across the platform)

**Symptom:**

When a mix up of stringified JSONdata and image are sent via http POST call, the server receives random amount of image via multer(`multer.any()`). The file is uploaded and exists in the server's public folder. `req.body` is also OK but  somehow I cannot access the `req.files`. it returns `undefined`. From heroku and my desktop localhost, the app runs fine. The image is uploaded OK, accessing `req.files` data has no problem as well. Only the VPS/CentOS7 server has got the problem.

**Client Side(React / Superagent / Babel / Webpack)**

```
import request from 'superagent'

request.post('/modwimg')
.query({
  //some token and other info goes here
})
.accept('application/json')
.field('data',JSON.stringify(jsonData))
.attach('image',this.state.imagedata)
.attach('bannerimage',this.state.bannerimagedata)
.then((res)=>{
  console.log('upload finished')
  this.setState({goback:true})
})
.catch((err)=>{

})
```

**Server Side**

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const multer = require('multer')
const pubDir = path.join(__dirname, 'pub')
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req,file,cb)=>{
    cb(null,'pub/')
  },
  filename: (req,file,cb)=>{
    cb(null,Date.now() + file.originalname)
  }
})
const upload = multer({storage:storage})

//allowing public access, image goes to public dir
app.use('/pub', express.static(pubDir))

/* initialize bodyparser to build up RESTful app */
//file size limit expansion
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit:'50mb', extended:true}))
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit:'50mb'}))

app.post('/imageupload',upload.any(),(req,res,next)=>{
  //some token approval goes here
  console.log(req.files) // <----this returns undefined data, but image is still uploaded
  console.log(req.body) // <---- this is fine!!

  //putting data(JSON.parse(req.body)) to db
  db.any( //....
  )
  //then respond to client
  res.json({result:true})
})
```

Comment: req.files had been removed from express some time ago as far as I remember

Comment: I am using the exact same version of node(latest stable 8.9.4) and app from both Heroku/desktop and my VPS. Then why is it working fine on my Heroku/desktop? and since the app is deployed via git `package.json` the express versions are virtually the same.

Comment: and I would like to know: req.files is no longer recommended for receiving file data? then what should I use for the substitution?

Comment: After searching on Google about req.files undefined problem and its substitute, people indeed still do use 'req.files' using bodyParser and multer. Why does it run fine on other testbeds, while on Linux it doesn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I've changed `extended` option to `extended:false` from `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit:'50mb', extended:true}))`, now it works like magic. I read from somewhere the `extended` option of `bodyParser` makes the rest of the http request data to some other format, so I've changed it and now it works.